# OS Xv6: I can't fill in some struct using the system call

Tags: c, xv6

There is some structure:

```
// Struct that represents a date object
struct rtcdate {
    uint seconds;
    uint minutes;
    uint hour;
    uint day;
    uint month;
    uint year;
};
`
```

and two system functions:

```
uint64 unixtime(); // Returns the current unixtime in seconds
void getrtcdate(unsigned long int unixtime, struct rtcdate *date) // Converts a given unix time in seconds to a rtcdate.
```

My question.
Right now I'm learning the OS XV6. I need to write some program for getting a system information about current time. For that I have to call the function getrtcdate() in corect way.

Here is my wrong code:

```
uint64  
sys_gettime(void)
{            
        struct rtcdate *date;
        if (argaddr(0,  &date) < 0)   // The functions argint, argaddr, and 
                                                       // argfd retrieve the n ’th system call
                                                       // argument, as either an integer, 
                                                       // pointer, or a file descriptor.
                return -1; 
        getrtcdate(unixtime(), date);

        return 0;
}
```

But unfortunately I'm getting a wrong output:
Date: 0. Not found 0

I want to understand in what way I can fill in the struct rtcdate throw the system function getrtcdate()

Comment: What is `argaddr`? In your client code, how do you call `gettime`?

Comment: And moreover, on which version of xv6 are you working? I can't find `getrtcdate` or `unixtime`....

Comment: @Mathieu 
getrtcdate() and unixtime() are defined in the local library

Comment: Okay, so we need you to post a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

you're making a bit of a mistake with how you're trying to access the passed in rtcdate struct. Since that is only a virtual user space memory address, you can't treat it as a normal pointer.

I'm going to assume you're using the TUM xv6 version, which includes functions for copying data from kernel to user space.

You need to initialize a local rtcdate struct, write to/modify it however you want, and then copy it over to user space using the `copyout` function found in `vm.h`.